# How to make radio button selected by default?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I work on my angularjs project I use bootstrap3 .

I have those radio buttons:

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = false; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null" selected>sites</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = true; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null">regions</label>
```

After page loaded I need by default sites radio button to be selected.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Use `ng-model` . See [radio docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Comment: @Michael, you should use **checked='checked'** attribute on sites radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **checked** attribute instead of selected attribute on sites radio button.

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = false; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null" checked='checked'>sites</label>

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = true; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null">regions</label>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqqkL5n6/) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = false; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null" ng-model="modelVar" ng-init="modelVar=true" ng-value="true">sites</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="toSeachBySiteNumber = true; list.filterArguments.siteDescription=null">regions</label>
```

use `ng-value="true"`

Comment: ng-value="true" dosen't work in my case, I used  ng-value="True" instead.